# What is fair compensation for being thrown out of hotel late at night for no lawful reason?

Tags: usa, hotels, florida

I am a law abiding senior citizen. Recently, a hotel chain made me leave late at night and move to another one of their local hotels because another guest claimed to be "threatened" by me. Nothing is further from the truth. Here's what happened:

Around 9 pm I heard barking across the hallway - it turned out to be 2 dogs left unattended. Another guest came out to the hall to see what was going on and said she also heard a cat. I called the manager who said she'd "try to reach the owners". She never called back 30 min later so I put a note on the guest's door which said if you are going out without your animals, you should take them with you. No threats, etc were made. Finally, the animals stopped barking and my phone rang. I'm thinking the manager is calling to apologize but instead she said "you must vacate the property in 1 hour and if you don't, I'll call the police because another guest feels threatened".

At first I thought this is a joke, but it wasn't. I told her the note didn't threaten at all and she should move the guest, and she declined so I said then move me and she said no but she would make arrangements at the same or lesser price at a close sister hotel, which she did. I had no choice but to get dressed, pack quickly and move to another one of their hotels (which was a dump).

I looked online and saw a guest with animals must sign a waiver in which they agree to pay more $; not keep more than 2 animals and if there is any disturbance to another guest, the hotel has the right to make other "arrangements" (i.e., move) the guest with animals. Not me!!!

The next day I spoke to the day manager about the incident and she said "I shouldn't even allow you to be on these premises anymore, but I can get you a room for the rest of the weekend if you'd like". I accepted but had to pack again and move back. It turns out the animal guest was thrown out that morning and was supposed to be there all weekend as well since the animals never stopped.

Besides being really embarrassed and inconvenienced, what is a fair remedy to me from the hotel?

I called and they are investigating.

Comment: Suggestion: mention what country this happened in. From your writing style and language I'm guessing the United States, but it's just a guess.

Comment: this took place in florida

Comment: Is the hotel part of a large branded chain or is it an independent operation? If the former, you could call them chain’s customer service. If they have a loyalty program, they would probably easily give you points or a voucher of some sort. I think the cost of you night would be a good target.

Comment: I am very sorry to hear that!!!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how much effort/time/money you are will to fight this.

Remember that time = money.

If there is a consumer protection bureau or ombudsman in Florida, you could contact them.

You should write a **strong, but civil** letter to the hotel stating the fact (include copies of the hotel bills and any other relevant documentation), and see how it goes.

At best they give you a couple free nights, at worse nothing happen and you stop going to that hotel chain.